# Loading, appending, and storing nested JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

So I generate a simple set of counts each day into a Pandas DataFrame. I would like to be able to timestamp it, add it to another DataFrame loaded from a JSON file, and then save it back to the JSON file. What I'm really struggling with is finding the right DataFrame structure and JSON format to make this work. Each day my program currently builds my DataFrame like this.

```
   Condition  Count
0  EPN        20
1  LOA        35
2  EMS        15
3  PPM        7
```

I need to combine it with a DataFrame which is pulled from a JSON file that hopefully looks like this:

```
               EMS EPN LOA
1543867981.55  5   17  18
```

So joining them looks like this:

```
               EMS EPN LOA PPM
1543867981.55  5   17  18  NaN
1543932370.90  15  20  35  7
```

And I'm trying to get it to save in something like this JSON format:

```
{"Time": "1543867981.55","Conditions":[{"EMS":5,"EPN":17,"LOA":18}],
 "Time": "1543932370.90","Conditions":[{"EMS":15,"EPN":20,"LOA":35,"PPM":7}]}
```

So far I haven't been able to crack it.

```
new_df = GetTodaysCount()
new_df.set_index('Condition')
new_df.columns=[str(time.time())]
new_df = new_df.transpose()  # I think I am now in my preferred format

#The closest I can get to loading in the dataframe from JSON file
with open("/filepath/sample.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
old_df = json_normalize(d['Conditions'])
#doesn't bring in timestamp as index, but if it did I would continue with:
final_df = pd.concat([new_df,old_df], sort=True)
final_df.to_json("/filepath/sample.json", orient='index')
```

But this stores the json like this:

```
{"1543867981.55":{"EMS":5,"EPN":17,"LOA":18,"PPM":null},
 "1543932370.90":{"EMS":15,"EPN":20,"LOA":35,"PPM":7}}
```

To clarify my only goals are: Timestamp daily DataFrames, combine it with running data from previous days into a DataFrame (so I can generate graphs of the various 'Conditions') and store the new combined data. I've chosen JSON because I thought it would be the cleanest way to store the data, and potentially find other uses for it, but that may have been a mistake.

**Edit:**
I'm against a deadline, so I went ahead and moved forward with this not exactly the way I needed it. My program works, but I had to ditch the nested json. I'm still interested in answer if anyone has it. For reference, this is what I am currently doing:

```
new_df = GetTodaysCount()
new_df.set_index('Condition')
new_df.columns=[str(round(time.time(),0))]
new_df = new_df.transpose()
old_json = pd.read_json("/filepath/sample.json", orient='index')
final_df = pd.concat([new_df,old_df], sort=True)
final_df.to_json("/filepath/sample.json", orient='index')
```

Comment: Your desired format doesn't make sense, JSON keys must be unique (just like Python dict keys, or javascript object attribute names...). Why do you want this format? What advantage does it give you over what `final_df.to_json` gives you? It *is* nested, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so a few things about your question:

json is actually not an efficient way to store data. It seems that you have only 2 dimensions (time and Condition). Why not store Condition as rows? In pandas you can pivot (`stack/unstack`) dimensions as needed. In my experience, you mainly only *need* to store data as json when the schema can not be determined or is subject to change.

If you already have a process that collects daily counts as of a timestamp, you should just append it to the existing data frame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
from datetime import datetime as dt

letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
conditions = []
for cond in range(20):
    cond = ''.join(list(np.random.choice(letters,3)))
    conditions.append(cond)

conds = list(np.random.choice(conditions,np.random.randint(3,6)))
counts = list(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(len(conds))))
ts = (1544479493.979077-87400)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dt.fromtimestamp(ts).date(), 'timestamp':dt.fromtimestamp(ts), 'conditions':conds, 'counts':counts})
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

conds = list(np.random.choice(conditions,np.random.randint(3,6)))
counts = list(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(len(conds))))
ts = (1544479493.979077)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dt.fromtimestamp(ts).date(), 'timestamp':dt.fromtimestamp(ts), 'conditions':conds, 'counts':counts})
df1.set_index('date',inplace=True)

df = df.append(df1)
print(df)

                            timestamp conditions  counts
date                                                    
2018-12-09 2018-12-09 13:48:13.979077        DWX      48
2018-12-09 2018-12-09 13:48:13.979077        TJC      95
2018-12-09 2018-12-09 13:48:13.979077        MFV       7
2018-12-10 2018-12-10 14:04:53.979077        AZQ      96
2018-12-10 2018-12-10 14:04:53.979077        BGX      23
2018-12-10 2018-12-10 14:04:53.979077        UFU      43
2018-12-10 2018-12-10 14:04:53.979077        WLT      85
```

​

now that your data is in this format, you can pivot it however you want easily in pandas:

```
df.groupby(['date','conditions']).sum().unstack('conditions')

           counts                                   
conditions    AZQ   BGX   DWX  MFV   TJC   UFU   WLT
date                                                
2018-12-09    NaN   NaN  48.0  7.0  95.0   NaN   NaN
2018-12-10   96.0  23.0   NaN  NaN   NaN  43.0  85.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. To the point of storing the data, you mention storing the data as rows. Do you mean in csv or some other format? I'm looking for a format with versatility and handles very large data sets (someone convinced me json was best for this).  (As a side note, i'm particularly fond of how you simulated data)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! feel free to upvote the answer if it helps. I played around with the various pd.to_json methods, and none seem to give you the output format you want. My recommendation is not to get hung up on the exact storage format unless you are sure it's an issue.

Comment: As a side note, json is not the best format for storage of large data (although you most likely won't run into performance issues until you reach millions of rows), because of a few reasons:
* values are stored as text instead of binary, which takes more memory
* highly regular data (data with many identical keys) wastes disc space
* computers are good at columnar operations, which means if you don't store the json optimally (as is possible in your goal), when trying to do a simple aggregation, you force the compute to traverse and parse all key value pairs.

Comment: Extremely helpful. I will store data in a csv instead. Thank you!